# Не могу запустить uvicorn Fast Api

Tags: python

Не могу запустить сервер unicorn. При запуске выдаёт такое [image: скриншот]

Что делать? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: `from typing import Uvicorn` - С чего вы решили, что uvicorn находится в модуле typing?

Comment: И что сделать нужно?

Comment: Заменить импорт на просто `import uvicorn`, потом приложение запускать через `uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=PORT)` (имя приложения, хост и порт свои подставляете).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `import uvicorn`

```
#импортируем библиотеку
# поднимаем наш app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(*ur_app*,ip, port)
```

Comment: Советую поднимать на локал хосте (127.0.0.1) порт любой резервный)

Можно также поднять все через терминал для этого: 
pip install uvicorn

uvicorn main:app --reload